# How to delete all nested keys with JQ

Tags: json, recursion, nested, jq, npm-shrinkwrap

I would like to delete all the resloved from a npm shrinwrap json file. this is causing a problem when running npm install on other machine.

```
 "cssstyle": {
      "version": "0.2.37",
      "from": "cssstyle@>=0.2.29 <0.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle/-/cssstyle-0.2.37.tgz"
    },
    "dashdash": {
      "version": "1.14.0",
      "from": "dashdash@>=1.12.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/dashdash/-/dashdash-1.14.0.tgz",
      "dependencies": {
        "assert-plus": {
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "from": "assert-plus@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/-/assert-plus-1.0.0.tgz"
        }
      }
    },
    "debug": {
      "version": "2.2.0",
      "from": "debug@>=2.2.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-2.2.0.tgz"
    }
```

How can I delete the resolved key from all the file

I'm using the pattern :

```
jq 'del(.resolved)' file.json
```

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion, the simplest approach to this kind of problem is to use `walk/1`:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("resolved") then del(.resolved) else . end)
```

If your jq does not have `walk/1` (which was only included as a builtin after the release of jq 1.5), then simply add its definition (easily available on the web) before the above line, or perhaps include it in your ~/.jq file.

Comment: In jq terminology, it's a filter, just like the one you provided. You can give it on the command line as you did, or put it in a file and invoke jq with the -f option.

Comment: How to add WALK ?

Comment: Until 1.6's release, you can download and install it from source https://github.com/stedolan/jq/tree/jq-1.6rc1 and install is by following the instructions in the README

Comment: The simplest way to make `walk` available is to include its def in your program. See https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ for its def and further details. The def can also be obtained from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedolan/jq/master/src/builtin.jq

Comment: Note that the has("resolved") is unnecessary. It seems like jq will just try to delete and if it can't nothing bad will happen. Might come in handy if you need to delete more than a few things